# How to remove a substring from a string in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

`string url = http://localhost:55914/tp://dev.dotcom.com/attachments/avatar/Faces9.jpg`

I want to remove the substring from localhost until the forward slashes before dev, how can I achieve that?

So the final string should be as follows:

`string final = http://dev.dotcom.com/attachments/avatar/Faces9.jpg`

Comment: did you try any code before posting here ?

Comment: You can use methods of String like String.Remove, String.Replace, String.Substring ,String.Split to achieve that, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8) is the document.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string url = @"http://localhost:55914/tp://dev.dotcom.com/attachments/avatar/Faces9.jpg";
    var urls = url.Split("//");
    string newUrl = urls[0] + "//" + urls[2];
```

split the string using `"//"` and join the splitted first and last value using `"//"`

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the specified substring

```
        string uri = "http://localhost:55914/tp://dev.dotcom.com/attachments/avatar/Faces9.jpg";
        uri = uri.Replace("http://localhost:55914/tp://", string.Empty);
```